# How to add a new value to a list everytime a 'while' loop occurs?

Tags: python

My problem is very basic, I'd say. I'm just starting to learn Python, but I can't do one little thing that is driving me mad.

I have a 'while' loop, and I want to add the value of a variable (that changes every loop too, as you can see in the code, the variable is the 'minutos_decorridos') to a list, everytime the loop occurs. 
Here's my code

```
minutos_decorridos = 0
lista_entradas = []
lista_saidas = []


while minutos_decorridos <= 15:
    minutos_decorridos=minutos_decorridos+1

lista_entradas.append(minutos_decorridos)
lista_saidas.append(minutos_decorridos)


print(lista_entradas)
print(lista_saidas)
```

The results are:
[16]
[16]

But my expected result is
[1,2,3,4,5,...,15,16]
[1,2,3,4,5,...,15,16]

Because I want it to add the value of the variable to the list every time the loop occurs. Note that the variable is increasing by 1 every loop too, that's why I'm expecting 1,2,3,4...15,16.

Comment: Move both of your append statements **inside the while loop**

Comment: By the way, both of the lists can simply be created with `list(range(1, 17))`

Answer (score 4):

Only the code that is indented will be executed in each iteration. You can simply move your append statements into the while loop, like so:

```
minutos_decorridos = 0
lista_entradas = []
lista_saidas = []


while minutos_decorridos <= 15:
    minutos_decorridos=minutos_decorridos+1
    lista_entradas.append(minutos_decorridos)
    lista_saidas.append(minutos_decorridos)


print(lista_entradas)
print(lista_saidas)
```

Comment: Didn't notice it! Can't believe it was that easy. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! One more piece of advice: You can also rewrite `minutos_decorridos=minutos_decorridos+1` as `minutos_decorridos+=1`. It's shorter and does the same thing :)

Comment: Will do! Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if you have done, other languages. But other languages like 'C++' uses curly braces to identify what goes inside the loop.

```
   While (i<15)
   {

        statement;
    }
```

However, in python, it is only indentation, that makes the statements inside a loop or condition.

Comment: Didn't try any other language yet, but the {} would certainly help. I'm having lots of problems with indentation on python. Thanks for the help.